# contentView tag question

Tags: iphone

I created contentViews and assigned tags. When I click row in simulator, I cannot get right tag value. Tag value is always 0.
What is wrong with my code?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{       
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];   

    UIImageView *imgView, *imgView1;   
    if(cell == nil)   
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];     
        cell.textLabel.text = @"test";

        imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100,0,20,62)];
        [imgView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"]];
        imgView.tag = 10;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:imgView];
        [imgView release];

        imgView1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200,0,20,62)];
        [imgView1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"]];
        imgView1.tag = 20;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:imgView1];
        [imgView1 release];

    }
    else
    {
        imgView = (id)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:10];
        imgView1 = (id)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:20];
    }   
    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (cell.contentView.tag == 10) // tag is always 0. What's wrong?
        NSLog(@"10");
    else if (cell.contentView.tag == 20)
        NSLog(@"20");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're querying the tag of the contentview, but adding the tag to a subview of the contentview.

```
CellView
    ContentView    //You're asking for the tag of this
        Subview    //But assigning the tag to this
```

Try `((UIView*)[cell.contentview subviews] objectAtIndex:0]).tag`

Comment: That's right. I have another question. How do I know if left content view is touched or right content view is touched?

Comment: The code in my response only returns the first subview. You could parse through all of them: `for (UIView *view in [cell.contentView subviews]){ int tag = view.tag; }`

Comment: I still don't know which view is touched. Maybe I have to post another question.

Comment: implement a touch delegate and include this: `if (CGRectContainsPoint(view.frame, touch.point)` for each of the views in your selected row

Answer (score 0):

cell.contentView.tag returns the tag of the cell contentView but in your code, you set the tag of the subviews (image view) of contentView.